# Unable To Run Docker File [Getting ERROR [builder 4/6] RUN npm install] 1.3s

Tags: visual-studio, dockerfile, npm-install

path /usr/package.json
#0 1.233 npm ERR! errno -2
#0 1.235 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/package.json'
#0 1.235 npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

I am running a dockerfile but it didn't get through it fails in RUN npm install command in docker file.[[image: Docker file image i am ring to run this file.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXbFv.png)]

Answer (score 3):

The error says it's not able to find the package.json file. There are two cases here-

1. If you're trying to copy json from your code to the docker image then you need to use the below command -

`COPY /<source-path>/filename /<destination-path>/filename`

In your case it would look like this -

`COPY /<path>/package.json package-lock.json`

2. If you're trying to copy a file from one directory to another within the container, you need to use the below command -

`RUN cp /<source-path>/filename /<destination-path>/filename`

In your case, it would look like

`RUN cp /<path>/package.json package-lock.json`

Comment: Thanks ! You covered almost all the possible scenarios!

Comment: @vasu Can you please Elaborate your error?